# how to enable a profile to mass update records?

Tags: administration, field-update

How do I enable a profile to be able to mass update records of a specific object in Salesforce?

Comment: I don't understand question... Any profile that have access to edit/create object is able to insert/update a list of objects.
So what you want achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This is all done through normal [object permissions](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=permissions_about_users_access.htm&language=en_US) that can be set on the [profile](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_userprofiles.htm) or as a [permission set](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=perm_sets_overview.htm&language=en_US). It is important to remember that the user will need to have access to the records through the [sharing model](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm) to be able to update them, otherwise they will not have access to those specific records. The easiest way to ensure they have access to every record of that object is to just give them [Modify All](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_view_all_mod_all.htm&language=en_US) access. This has several downsides to it in terms of security however so please be aware of that.

Overall, it is really just a combination of your object permissions and sharing model.